# C# Dotnet Core 3.1 - Load Assembly on Runtime

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, .net-assembly

I'm currently trying to load an assembly on Runtime.

I'm using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path)`.
Then, with the `DependencyContext` and the `CompositeCompilationAssemblyResolver`, I load unresolved dependcies using - Compile || Runtime - properties. 
Finally I fallback to load them directly from the Directory Path if they are yet not found.

However, dependices are still missing on some projects. Like the following

> "Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll'
>   file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core"

Even if it's found inside Compile or Runtime libs, `TryResolveAssemblyPaths` seems unable to locate them :/

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

Well, After some research it appears than post 3.1 version of dotnet core framwork, some dependencies are directly loaded inside the SDK itself. Preventing you to load them manually through **ICompilationAssemblyResolver** or else.

So if you face that probleme with certain projects, apply same SDK on caller/callee (or import them). **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web** for example.

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview

And: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md

**EDIT 2:**

I suggest you to read this issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1050

Mr Vitek Karas answer to this problem in a more accurate manner.

Answer (score 2):

what i am understand is you cannot load your assemply from path

so first get the path

```
 string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/dllname.dll");
```

then

```
 load =AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
```

Comment: Edit my post, the scope of the problem wasn't about path resolution, but really dependency resolve. Thanks you anyway :)